# Problema ao salvar informações no localstorage via js

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Pessoal estou querendo salvar meu `timer` no `local storage` mais ele não esta salvando isso quando entro no meu console ele não aparece segue meu código HTML e JS

html

```
 <div id="timer">
          <span id="minutes"></span>:<span id="seconds"></span>
        </div>
```

JS

```
window.onload = function() {
  var access = localStorage.getItem('firstAccess');

  if(access == '') {
    var d = new Date();
    console.log(d);
    var time = localStorage.setItem('firstAccess', JSON.stringify(d));
    setTimer(time);
  }
  else {
     setTimer(access);     
  }
 function setTimer(time) {
     var timespan = countdown(time).toString();
     $('#minutes').html(timespan.minutes);
     $('#seconds').html(timespan.seconds);
 }
}
```

Console:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui é aonde deveria aparecer o nome do set Item que é firstAccess
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Da algum erro no `console`?

Comment: @RafaelAugusto não mais vou colocar o print do console na pergunta mais não sei porque não salva deve ter algum probleminha no código que não percebi

Comment: Respondi sua pergunta com o erro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está fazendo errado. nesse `if`

```
 if(access == '') {
    var d = new Date();
    console.log(d);
    var time = localStorage.setItem('firstAccess', JSON.stringify(d));
    setTimer(time);
  }
```

troque para isso

```
 if(!access) {
    var d = new Date();
    console.log(d);
    localStorage.setItem('firstAccess', JSON.stringify(d));
    var time = localStorage.firstAccess
    setTimer(time);
  }
```

Comment: Obrigado vou testar aqui

Comment: @Kirito Beleza, depois avisa se funcionou

Answer (score 3):

Altere a linha:

```
if(access == '') {
```

para:

```
if(access == null) {
```

Este é o valor *default* de retorno do método `localStorage.getItem()` para uma chave não-populada.